# Python requests library: looping requests.get()

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I have a script which I want to get data from an api every 30s. I am using the requests module however every loop seems to return the same data. See the below "sample code":

```
import requests
from something import dosomething

http_proxy  = "http://user:password@someproxy.com:8080"
https_proxy = "http://user:password@someproxy.com:8080"
ftp_proxy   = "http://user:password@someproxy.com:8080"
proxyDict = {"http"  : http_proxy, "https" : https_proxy, "ftp"   : ftp_proxy}
url = "someapi.com"
g=requests.get(url,proxies=proxyDict)

try:
    keep_running = True
    while keep_running:
        try:
            dosomething(g.content)
```

So I need to tell requests to close a session or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use `.sessions` statement at the beginning of loop and use the `.close` statement at the end of the loop.