# Python requests module, how to issue multiple requests in the for loop?

Tags: python, python-requests

I wonder why when I call requests.get() method consequentially, like this:

```
response = requests.get(url.format("set"))
print(response.status_code)
response = requests.get(url.format("map"))
print(response.status_code)
response = requests.get(url.format("list"))
print(response.status_code)
response = requests.get(url.format("vector"))
print(response.status_code)
response = requests.get(url.format("string"))
print(response.status_code)
```

I got OK status for all requests, but when I do it in the for loop, like:

```
for word in fIn :
        response = requests.get(url.format(word))
        if(response.status_code == 200):
            print "OK"
        else:
            print(response.status_code)
            print "Error"
            print word
```

I got 400(Error) for all requests except the last one.

Additional info:
there is [related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36853651/python-requests-get-iterating-url-in-a-loop), where are mentioned 2 ways of coping with this situation: wait, headers.
wait doesn't work in my situation
and about headers - I don't know what to provide there.

Update:
specific version, that I am trying to implement:

```
from lxml import html

import requests

fOut = open("descriptions.txt","w")

with open('dummyWords.txt') as fIn:
    for word in fIn :
        print word
        response = requests.get(url.format(word))
        if(response.status_code == 200):
            print "OK"
        else:
            print(response.status_code)
            print(word)
```

Comment: Do they have a rate limit on requests?

Comment: @Tim I am aware of rate limit, I don't know whether they have one. But it seems strange for me that typing requests manually works, while using for loop not. Maybe in the for loop every time new object for session is created and new session is established, while in manual requests one session is used?

Comment: Is this of any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31306501/python-requests-library-looping-requests-get

Comment: @spin_eight if you are typing them manually then perhaps you're doing one per half a second? The loop will do all 6 in 0.1 seconds, likely breaking a rate somewhere.

Comment: @Tim of course I have the script with them typed in manually (this is my fault, I should be more clear about how I do it, I thought that it is evident), so I simply run my script

Comment: Looks like you are trying to get the input from a B.S. source like a file (`fIn` is very unclear here). Try explicitly doing `for word in ('set', 'map', 'list', 'vector', 'string'):` for a start.

Comment: I doubt the issue is the loop itself since I would expect the unlooped commands to run faster, if anything. The problem is most likely with what you are passing to the loop.

Comment: @Tim. It's being done the same number of times in either case. The looped version is in an `if` block, in a `for` loop, so I would expect it to have quite a bit more overhead. That being said, the overhead will probably be much less than the print itself, as you mentioned.

Comment: @spin_eight Please post the code that makes `fIn`.

Comment: Also, if you don't mind sharing, a sample of `url` that we can use to test.

Comment: @MadPhysicist please see update version.

Comment: @Bahrom - link you gave my look interesting, but I don't know where to put sessions + close

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have trailing newlines that you need to *strip* off:

```
with open('dummyWords.txt') as fIn:
    for word in map(str.strip, fIn) :
```

It works for the last as you obviously have no newline at the end of the last word in the file. `"www.foo.com\n"` is not the same as `"www.foo.com"`

Comment: I think standard is you should have a newline at the end of the last line. If he does or not, is different. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline

Comment: @Tim, you are free to edit a file as you please, what  you cannot do is add newlines to urls and expect them to work.

Comment: My comment refers to the penultimate sentence - he *should* have one there, but he clearly doesn't.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham great!!! I initially thought about it on my way home and this idea somehow vanished! Of course that is it!!! Thank you for you attentive look! Have a nice time of a day!! Best regards!

Comment: @spin_eight, no worries, you too.

Answer (score 0):

Encoding POST data resolved issue for me.

```
cmd = urllib.quote(cmds[i])
```

For my testcases

- No newline required
- No sleep time required